# When replacing medians in an unknown category get NA in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets

```
d1=structure(list(et = c("s", "s"), gg = c("d", "d"), hj = c("f", 
"f"), ggh = c("h", "h"), wer = c(23L, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

and

```
d2=structure(list(et = c("s", "s"), gg = c("d", "d"), hj = c("f", 
"f"), ggh = c("h", "f"), wer = c(3L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I perform changing value according to principle that if in the dataset `d2` the value `wer` for the same categories with `d1`, less or greater than the median from `d1` for this category on 1, then in d2 put the value of the median in this category.

To be more clear what i want ,  for this categoty from `d1`

```
et  gg  hj  ggh (this categorical vars)
s   d   f   h
```

median by wer=34

d2 has same category `s   d   f   h` where wer=3, so 3<34 so i must change this value on 34,
but also d2 has category `s d   f   f` which is absent in d1, so we left value for unknown category in d1.

Now i use code

```
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  group_by(across(-wer)) %>% 
  summarise(wer = median(wer), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  right_join(d2, by = c("et", "gg", "hj", "ggh"), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  mutate(wer = ifelse(wer >= wer.y, wer, wer.y), .keep = "unused")
```

it does what I need, however, for an unknown category in d1, it puts down NA
result

```
  et    gg    hj    ggh     wer
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 s     d     f     h        34
2 s     d     f     f        NA
```

But instead must be real value for this category from d2 like this

```
  et    gg    hj    ggh     wer
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 s     d     f     h        34
2 s     d     f     f        7
```

How can i fix it ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Replace `ifelse(wer >= wer.y, wer, wer.y)` with `coalesce(ifelse(wer >= wer.y, wer, wer.y), wer.y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison operators returns `NA` when there is an `NA`

```
> 7 > NA
[1] NA
```

In the code, we just need to do the correction for `NA` by adding a condition using `is.na`

```
library(dplyr)
d1 %>% 
   group_by(across(-wer)) %>% 
   summarise(wer = median(wer), .groups = "drop") %>% 
   right_join(d2, by = c("et", "gg", "hj", "ggh"), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
   mutate(wer = ifelse(wer >= wer.y & !is.na(wer), wer, wer.y), .keep = "unused")
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  et    gg    hj    ggh     wer
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 s     d     f     h        34
2 s     d     f     f         7
```